# How do I paste a column of hyperlinks?

Tags: microsoft-excel

This seems like a simple question, but I can't figure out the answer. How do I paste a bunch of hyperlinks?

Please see the screenshot I've posted.

[image: Excel Screenshot]

As you see, I have a column of text. Each row of text is actually a hyperlink. I don't need the text, but I need the URLs. How do I paste all those rows of text as URLs? I thought there was a "paste special" option, but if there is, I'm not seeing it.

Currently, I'm going cell by cell, right-clicking "Edit Hyperlink," and then manually copying and pasting. This is rather tedious, so I'd like to know how to do it all at once (if possible).

Any ideas?

Comment: I assume paste special - links only paste the text portion and not the underlying web address. Do you have a source for the bulk form of the web address links?

Comment: I don't have the source code directly. They are pasted in directly from LinkedIn.

Comment: If you copy a linked text, then you are getting the text with embedded link. The other way is to right click the source on the browser and select "copy link address"; you'd have to do that for each source that you copy from the start. In your example, however, there is no way around what you are already doing.

Comment: If you have so many links that it's simply a days work, then you might want to look into AHK, but it's a learning curve if you're not already exposed to programming functionality. There are keyboard shortcuts for editing links too: CTRL+K,CTRL+C,ESC; or CTRL(K,C), ESC. This puts the link into the Clipboard with a few keystrokes. These keystrokes could be "programmed" into AHK. But like I said, if you aren't already exposed to basic programming principles it would be a learning curve that would take some invested time.

Answer (score 0):

First paste normally.  Then selected the pasted block and run this short macro:

```
Sub HyperFixer()
    Dim h As Hyperlink
    Dim rng As Range
    For Each h In ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks
        Set rng = h.Range
        If Not Intersect(rng, Selection) Is Nothing Then
            h.TextToDisplay = h.Address
        End If
    Next h
End Sub
```

The "friendly" name of each hyperlink will be changed to reflect the actual *URL*.